# Mikrotik exclude an IP address from simple queue

Tags: bandwidth, queue

I limited internet bandwidth of the range `192.168.100.0/24` using a simple queue in Mikrotik. Now I want to exclude some IP addresses (e.g `192.168.100.20`) from this range to have unlimited internet bandwidth.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two simple queue: One for `192.168.100.0/24` which is limited and another for `192.168.100.20` which is unlimited. The simple queue for specific IP address should be upper than other queue. I could be done by Drag & Drop the queue in `Winbox`. Also you can create this queues and keep their priority using following commands:

```
/queue simple
add name=ExcludedIP target=192.168.100.20/32
add max-limit=2M/2M name=RangeLimit target=192.168.100.0/24
```

Comment: it is ok but if he need more then one address, he can add many address to one quene

Comment: @AdamSilenko: A simple queue can have multiple targets but every targets have the same speed limitation.Two distinct speed limitations need two simple queue.

Comment: of course, but if he need many Excluded ip then he don't need another queue... (my english isn't very good)

Comment: @AdamSilenko : For big network `Packet Mark` should be use to simplify managment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use packet mark or define multiple target address on queue.

Comment: You mean I should create a simple queue which target field contains `192.168.100.0/24` and `192.168.100.20`?

Comment: like @SuB i mean that you need additional queue (at begin) for some addresses ... (but you can use packet mark in queues definition)

Comment: @AdamSilenko : Packet mark is not necessary in this simple situation.

Comment: he can use packet mark (not should), he can use marks on other task, and this could be a part of complete solution...